# WCF JSON: Sending / Parsing an array of mixed object types

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to send an array of related but not the same type of objects from a server as JSON via a WCF service. When attempting to return an array of object[], the WCF service fails. I also thought a step further, how would I even parse that on the client?

I came up with a solution using a JsonWrapper class. Instead of sending object[] I send JsonWrapper[]. The returned JSON looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Json":"{\"Id\":\"abc\"}",
        "Type":"DemoServer.Foo"
    },
    {
        "Json":"{\"Id\":\"def\",\"Count\":3}",
        "Type":"DemoServer.Bar"
    }
]
```

As you can see, I'm double serializing the JSON which means I have to deserialize the returned array and then deserialize each item individually. I somewhat like this approach as the objects don't have to be binary compatible on both the Server and the Client. Somehow the double serializing of the JSON feels wrong.

Is there a better approach to this? I'm using WCF on the server and Json.net on the client. I'm aware of the "__type" parameter but I'm not sure this is the solution to my problem.

Comment: In terms of your WCF data contract, are you aware of the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).  Thats how you tell WCF the potential subclasses of your return value.  Did you experiment with that?